# Pregenerated Meta tag wikis aren't rendered correctly

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, per-site-meta

Some tags on per-site Metas have automatically generated excerpts and wikis. These don't exist as posts until somebody edits them. Four of them link to other tags with the `[meta-tag:status-planned]` syntax, but those links are not rendered:

[image]

- https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info
- https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-norepro/info
- https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-planned/info
- https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-reproduced/info

As soon as they're edited (even if it's a 'null' edit), the text is rendered correctly (i.e. they look like [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)).

Comment: Now I see that the [question (bug-report) I posted today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379090) is rather similar to yours. (I should have expected this. :-)