# Why is [meta-tag:status-planned] not rendered in this tag info?

Tags: bug, status-review, markdown, tag-wiki, moderator-tags

I have noticed that the tag info for [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) on [MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/status-deferred/info) contains the paragraph looks like this:

> Contrast [meta-tag:status-planned], in which a feature is something that the site developers have definitively approved for implementation but the timing is unknown.

On the same site, it renders fine in the preview while editing.

At the same time, on [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info) and on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info), this renders just fine. I.e., it looks like this:

> Contrast [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), in which a feature is something that the site developers have definitively approved for implementation but the timing is unknown.

Only later - both from the answer and from similar Glorfindel's post "[Pregenerated Meta tag wikis aren't rendered correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351015)" - I've realized that there are the same problems with the tag info for [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) and [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

---

**The main question:** What is the reason that the status tag isn't rendered as a tag here? Can this be somehow fixed?

---

I did not make an effort to systematically test all sites (or try whether this can be checked in some way using a network-wide SEDE query). But from the few sites that I've tried, the tag info is rendered correctly on [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info).
It is rendered incorrectly on
[Arduino](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[German](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Politics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info),
[Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info), and
[Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info).

At least for the sites that I tried, the hypothesis suggested in comments might be correct - the sites where the tag isn't rendered in the tag info are the ones where this tag info doesn't have a revision history. (See also: [The imported tag info for default tags is ignored in revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289713).)

**Added later.** To help a bit with quantifying how many sites might have similar problem in this particular tag info, I have created a small SEDE query. According to SEDE, only [27 sites have the tag info for *status-deferred*](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1600006/tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status-deferred&types=5) and only [26 sites have the tag info for *status-planned*](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1600006/tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status-planned&types=5). Looking at the other three tags, [9 sites have a tag wiki for *status-norepro*](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1600006/tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status-norepro&types=5), [9 sites for *status-reproduced*](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1600006/tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status-reproduced&types=5) and [14 sites for *status-bydesign*](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1600006/tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status-bydesign&types=5). (Some of them were created only recently - this post lead to some manual edits. Some of those edits are still pending. All numbers as of May 29.) So the remaining sites probably have the version imported together with these default tags - which includes the mistake mentioned above.

Here are some additional SEDE queries which might help to find the sites where this problem could manifest:

- [Tag-wikis on metas for the given tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1600006/tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status-bydesign&types=5). (In queries related to a specific tag, I am using [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as an example. Of course, the same query can be used for other tags - or even [all status tags at the same time](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1600006/tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status%25&types=5) - by changing the parameter tagname.)
- [Tag-wikis for the given tag with empty body](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1602172/tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-with-empty-body-only-metas-networkwide?num=1000&types=5&tagname=status-bydesign)
- [Missing tag-wikis for the given tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1602173/missing-tag-wikis-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status-bydesign)
- [Missing tag-excerpt for the given tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1602174/missing-tag-excerpts-for-the-given-tag-only-metas-networkwide?tagname=status-bydesign)
- For comparison: [List of all metas](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1601191/list-of-all-meta-sites)
- [Pending suggested edits on metas](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1601770/the-oldest-pending-edit-suggestions-only-tag-info-all-metas?num=1000) and a similar query [with more details](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1606584/pending-edit-suggestions-only-tag-info-including-tagname-all-metas?num=1000)

---

I have previously posted here a question related to a difference between the preview and the final form of the tag wiki: [Why is there a difference between rendering of links in tag wiki and in editing preview?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292231) But that one is different - it is not about the tags, but about the titles of the linked posts.

---

Here is a screenshot showing what I see on MathOverflow Meta:

[image: Screenshot from MO meta]

When I click on edit, in the preview everything looks fine:

[image: Screenshot showing the editing preview]

On Mathematics Meta, the same tag info is rendered without any problems:

[image: Screenshot from Mathematics Meta]

Comment: I can only speculate but the tag doesn't have a post associated with it: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1599939 so I assume that the server-side render of that wiki never happened, or at least didn't happen after the `meta-tag` markdown came into existence. As those wiki's don't have an history either I assume this gets resolved as soon as you make an edit to that tag wiki. I do hope Mathoverflow then runs a serverside render that is up to date enough to parse and convert the meta tag into the correct html.

Comment: @rene I'd prefer not to edit that tag-info - if this is an example of some problem which might appear elsewhere, I think it is better to leave it untouched so that somebody can investigate. (Moreover, ATM I am out of suggested edits on that particular meta.)
I will just mention that on [math.meta.se], there aren't any [posts tagged status-planned either](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned). (Although on that site, there [is a revision history](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/31906/revisions). ...

Comment: ... Some problems with revision history for default tags on meta [have been reported before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289713).)
On both metas mentioned above, (status-planned) has been used at least once in the past: [MathOverflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1105163/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagName=status-planned), [Mathematics](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1105163/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagName=status-planned).

Comment: what is the use of `<b></b>`?

Comment: @NotStandingwithGoGotaHome I was unable to replicate exactly the way the tag-info was rendered - this was added by an editor [in revision 9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/379090/9).

Comment: @Martin I know that :), You put an empty HTML tag there (essentially a "stub" or "dummy" tag), right? no change in the document, but the powerful enough to send *tag-finder-renderer* away. Very nice, smart and interesting way... everyday you learn a new thing.

Comment: FYI, suggested edits on Metas can take a [long, long time](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20) to be reviewed ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Certainly, it can be [quite long](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1601742/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-tag-info-all-metas) - reviewing on per-site-metas isn't that active. If several edits are suggested at the same time, the red dot might speed things a bit. (On the sites which I frequent, the longest time I've seen [was several months](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2021/7/30).) OTOH, this certainly isn't something that could be considered urgent - it's almost two years since your bug report.

Answer (score 10):

I talked to Adam about this and it seems that I'm correct - as far as he can tell, for the default templates we don't actually process the Markdown. I've added a status-review tag to the question so that we can fix it but it'll only address newly-created templates, not the existing ones.

It looks fine when you click edit because the preview is rendering it in the browser. But when we create content, it's rendered from Markdown to HTML when it's created and only updated when it's edited - except, apparently - with these tag wikis.

Saving a new version will fix the issue - sometimes you don't even need to edit the content, just click "edit" and then "save". When I was looking at the MathOverflow one on my phone, it didn't actually save the newly-rendered version but I've since been able to get it to render on Proof Assistants and Adam was able to get it to work on Substrate & Polkadot.

The short-term solution is identifying the sites where this needs to be re-rendered and submitting edits. The long-term solution here will be making sure that we're rendering the MD when these default templates are created.

Comment: Of course, if manual editing is the only way to fix this, that would mean that the same edit would be needed for almost all other sites. (And going through all per-site-metas one by one seems rather cumbersome way to fix this.) Does this mean that whenever a new sites is created, the per-site-meta will have this specific tag-info with the incorrect rendering?

Comment: You wrote *I saved a new edit and it now renders properly" did you mean edit on some per site meta? I do not see any changes on the meta sites linked in the question - and no edits [in your recent activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/3979517/catija?tab=activity). So I am bit confused about the claims in this answer, when compared with  what is actually displayed in the tag-infos on per-site-metas.

Comment: @Martin: It seems they created a tag-wiki for the [status-planned] tag: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/5350/revisions

Comment: ... Weird. It looked fine immediately after I edited. I've re-edited and it (again) looks fine ... let's see if it sticks this time.

Comment: Yup, [it's fixed now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkvAy.png) :)

Comment: @Justin I did not realize that edits to tag-wikis are [hidden in the network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86656). It is shown in the activity [on the meta profile](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/122216/catija?tab=activity).

Comment: @Catija Thanks for editing this on MathOverflow. There are many other sites with the same problem - so the only thing to do is to edit all of them manually one by one? Similarly, will the same problem appear whenever a new site is created? (Feel free to [ping me in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1632/2022/5/28) if you think that this comment thread has grown too long and that it is better to continue there.)

Comment: @Martin See update - there was only so much I could investigate on the weekend. ;)

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the update. If I understood correctly, for the existing sites this can only be done by manual edits. I tried to made suggested edits to (status-deferred) and (status-planned) on most of the sites - with the exception of *other language versions of SO*. (I was hesitant to edit something in a language which I do not understand.) After the next update of SEDE I'll try to check using the query in the question on which sites the suggested edits went through - then only (status-norepro) and (status-reproduced).